# different appearance about a:active in ie7 and ie8

Tags: css

Recently i met a bug which confused me a lot. for example,here i put a a tag,which has a style
 `a{font:14px}` and `a.active{font:18px}`. in ie8,this work perfect.when i click the tag,its font size became 18px,and when i release the mouse ,it turned to 14px. yet in ie7,after i clicked the tag ,its size became 18px and when i release the mouse,its font size did not change.and if i cilck other area of the page ,its font size turned back 14px;I

```
    .button:active{
         font-size:18px;
}
```

Comment: IE7 is full of bugs, what's your question?

Comment: @FDL Who told IE7 is full of bugs.  Its just an **old version** without new features.

Comment: don't you want  `a:active` instead ?

Comment: @Frederik.L not tye problem.the problem is in ie7,when i released the mouse the a tag did not change its fontsize.it should turn back 14px.how to du?

Comment: @user2446213 If you are looking for a way to change IE7's behavior, no one can help here. But if you're looking to add some consistence in your code so that older browsers can render it correctly, we might. Can you provide all the relevant code including the markup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that IE7 is considering the anchor still "active" because it hasn't lost the focus yet. That would actually make sense (maybe not). Other browsers, though, consider it inactive as soon as the mouse button is released, which we usually take for granted.

If you really want to handle `mousedown` and `mouseup` events on a link, I think you will need to deal with it in JS:

**Plain JS solution**

```
var a = document.getElementById("myLink");
a.onmousedown=function(){
    this.setAttribute("class", "active");
};

a.onmouseup=function(){
    this.setAttribute("class", "");
};
```

**jQuery solution**

```
var $a=$('#myLink');
$a.mousedown(function(){
   $(this).addClass('active');
   // this is actually much more scalable, if you don't mind using jQuery
});

$a.mouseup(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('active'); // and this as well
});
```